# How to get oauth_verifier in TwitterOAuth for PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I already got `oauth_token`

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => 'oob'));
$oauth_token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
```

And I need to get `oauth_verifier` for the next step:

```
$token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", ["oauth_verifier" => $oauth_verifier]);
```

How can I do it? I know that `oauth_verifier` can be found in $_REQUEST, but what request do I need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth-20--cms-25713

from above link you can have more info to have verifier

Comment: Thank you. But I need to write an app that automaticaly reads the public twits of some users. Without any actions of user, like this:  https://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-1-1-oauth-php/
(but code from this link returned me `[message] => Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34`)